# Azure Api Service and Individual accounts

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I've originally used Web API 2 with Individual Accounts so that users can create a new account by supplying a username/email and password which is stored in my DB.

I'm now looking to put this API into Azure API service and have looked at the documentation about [authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth/)  but this mostly talks about external authentication. Can we use Individual Accounts with Azure API or will I need to handle this myself within the actual API?

Also, with the third party authentication all the examples use a redirected website (FaceBook, Google) to get the user to log in. I want to call this from a mobile app so does it support extenal authentication using API calls or will I have to do that myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The is no problem in using the security you originally used. The documentation you are looking at describes how to do claim based authentication, authentication with azure ad and internally secure your application with service principals. When using a mobile device, you can go with claims authentication. However you should first figure out what you really want to do.